# android application prevent sql file from reverse engineering

Tags: android, sql, drawable, reverse-engineering

I have an application android that doesn't need connexion internet, all content of the application is on a .sql file on the folder raw, the problem when I publish the application, anybody from the APK can get this .sql file by a simply extract

how can I hide or encode this .sql file please to avoid people getting this .sql file?

Thank you for your response

Comment: google for `sqlcipher`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tencent's wcdb](https://github.com/Tencent/wcdb) or [greenDao](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO) for encrypting your text in sqlite